# Restrict comma in asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to restrict the use of comma in textbox. Initially the textbox is disabled and only when the user clicks on a related checkbox, the textbox is enabled.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
function checkForComma(keyCode) {
    if (event.keyCode == 188) {
        alert('Not allowed');
    }
}
```

And the EditorTemplate:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine1, @Model.isUsed ? 
    (object)new { @class = "form-control" } : 
    new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled", @onkeypress = "checkForComma(this);" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AddressLine1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to place return `false` in your function. modify you function following

```
function checkForComma(event) {
    if (event.charCode == 44) {
        alert('Not allowed');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also modify your html code as following

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine1, @Model.isUsed ? 
    (object)new { @class = "form-control" } : 
    new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled", @onkeypress = "return checkForComma(event);" })
```

Comment: Does your alert message display?

Comment: No nothing is displayed

Comment: how can I allow comma in the textbox and restrict it at the end of text entered

Comment: you need to check that on any button click or on blur of text box.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: I have used the same code and instead of using @onkeypressed in the EditorTemplate I have used `@onblur = "return checkForComma(event);"` But I am not getting the desired o/p